# How to remove event listener on component unmount react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm console logging every 2 seconds in handleSlide function and I want it to run everytime the component mounts .

```
    const handleSlide = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log('runs');
        }, 2000);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('load', handleSlide);
        return () => {
            return window.removeEventListener('load', handleSlide);
        };
    }, []);
```

The problem is the handleSlide function still runs after unmount and I see the console log on other pages and components as well .

How can I remove an event listener in reactjs when a component unmounts ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using setInterval and it runs every 2 seconds when it is mounting. you need a callback function to clear it at certain condition. either your interval runs every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really removing the interval. Your `handleSlide` function registers an anonymous `setInterval`. You can clear it by calling [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). However you need to pass an ID for that which is conveniently returned by [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Your code could look like this

```
yourID = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('runs');
        }, 2000);
```

and then in your callback

```
clearInterval(yourID)
```